# Create logic to populate lower level values in a bill of material query

Tags: sql-server

I'm working on a query that displays a bill of materials with three items (parent and two children), a parent lead time (can vary depending on the part number), ship date, and quantity.

I need to create logic that would populate the children quantity columns with the quantity related to the "parent" ship date plus the "parent" lead time.

For instance, for the ship date of 12/05/2018, the 'child' quantity (BOM levels 2 and 3) should show the quantity from the parent for ship date 12/07/2018 (ship date plus lead time(2)). Please see the code and screen print below. Appreciate any suggestions. Thanks.

```
CREATE TABLE #RELEASE
(
ITEM_NO VARCHAR(25),
BOM_LEVEL INT,
LEAD_TIME INT,
SHIP_DATE DATETIME,
QUANTITY INT
);

INSERT #RELEASE VALUES ('A1', 1, 2, '12/05/2018', 100);
INSERT #RELEASE VALUES ('A2', 2, 0, '12/05/2018', 140);
INSERT #RELEASE VALUES ('A3', 3, 0, '12/05/2018', 140);
INSERT #RELEASE VALUES ('A1', 1, 2, '12/06/2018', 120);
INSERT #RELEASE VALUES ('A2', 2, 0, '12/06/2018', 160);
INSERT #RELEASE VALUES ('A3', 3, 0, '12/06/2018', 160);
INSERT #RELEASE VALUES ('A1', 1, 2, '12/07/2018', 140);
INSERT #RELEASE VALUES ('A2', 2, 0, '12/07/2018', 180);
INSERT #RELEASE VALUES ('A3', 3, 0, '12/07/2018', 180);
INSERT #RELEASE VALUES ('A1', 1, 2, '12/08/2018', 160);
INSERT #RELEASE VALUES ('A2', 2, 0, '12/08/2018', 0);
INSERT #RELEASE VALUES ('A3', 3, 0, '12/08/2018', 0);
INSERT #RELEASE VALUES ('A1', 1, 2, '12/09/2018', 180);
INSERT #RELEASE VALUES ('A2', 2, 0, '12/09/2018', 0);
INSERT #RELEASE VALUES ('A3', 3, 0, '12/09/2018', 0);

SELECT * FROM #RELEASE
```

[image]

Comment: So, that sample data and screenshot show us "what you have", correct? Are you also able to present "what you want" in some manner beyond the narrative (e.g. another screenshot)? I'm having trouble working out exactly what you're after. Also, how are rows interrelated based on this data? (Bearing in mind that tables have no inherent order)

Comment: Actually, the screenshot shows what I'm after. What I currently have is the same screen shot with "zero" quantities for the child items. The release quantities for the children items take into consideration the parent "lead time", in this case 2, so their "buckets" need to be populated by the parent quantity related to their "ship date + lead time". Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
SELECT c.*, '<-- Children-- | --Parent -->', p.*
From #RELEASE c
    LEFT OUTER JOIN #RELEASE p ON c.QUANTITY = p.QUANTITY 
                                AND p.BOM_LEVEL = 1
                                AND c.SHIP_DATE = DATEADD(DAY, -p.LEAD_TIME, p.SHIP_DATE)
WHERE c.BOM_LEVEL != 1
```

Comment: Chjquest, Thank you very much for solution!